# Setting XML Namespace sets it empty in children

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I want to set the namespace of the root element in a XML file which works:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "no"));
XNamespace ns = @"http://mynamespace.de/test";
doc.Add(new XElement(ns + "RootElement"));
doc.Root.Add(new XElement("SomeChildElement"));
```

But the direct child elements do have an empty `xmlns` attribute. How can I avoid that? I only want the namespace set in the root element.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236890/when-will-other-sites-follow-stack-overflow-portuguese#comment776600_236890

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the direct child elements do have an empty xmlns attribute. How can I avoid that?

You specify the namespace for the child elements as well:

```
doc.Root.Add(new XElement(ns + "SomeChildElement"));
```

The point is that elements inherit the closest `xmlns=...` namespace specification. When you just use `new XElement("SomeChildElement")` that's actually creating an element with an *empty* namespace URI, so the `xmlns=""` would be required in order to give it the right namespace. If you want:

```
<RootElement xmlns="http://mynamespace.de/test">
  <SomeChildElement />
</RootElement>
```

Then you really want a `SomeChildElement` element *with the same namespace* as the root element - which is what the code at the top of my answer will give you.

Note that you don't need the verbatim string literal for the namespace, by the way - a regular string literal is fine, as the URI doesn't contain any backslashes or new lines:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://mynamespace.de/test";
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want the namespace **only** set in the root element.

Comment: @juergend: I suspect you don't understand namespace defaulting then. Either you want the child element in the same namespace as the root element (in which case it will inherit it without needing `xmlns=...`) or you *don't* want it in any namespace (in which case your document will *correctly* include `xmlns=""`).